# Iterate over multiple tuples in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

How to iterate over multiple tuples, to define `+`, `-`, `*` etc. operations? I would like to add math operations for 2D and 3D points.

Doing it by hand is too verbose

```
proc `+`(a: (int, int), b: (int, int)): (int, int) =
  (a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1])
  
echo (1, 1) + (2, 2)
```

Would be better to iterate over tuple content. How to do it, it needs to iterate over 3 tuples, `a`, `b` and `result`.

```
proc `+`[T: tuple](a: T, b: T): T =
  # ?
  discard

echo (1, 1) + (2, 2)
```

Additionally, is there a way to restrict the tuple type to only `tuple of floats` or `tuple of floats or ints`?

Comment: Seems that you try to abuse tuples for which Nim has the array data type. When all fields have the same type, a seq or array is the obvious container, and when length is a constant, then array. Well you may prefer tuples due to better support for automatic tuple unpacking or to access fields by index and name interchangeable. But then you may have to create a macro for iterating the fields, maybe like the fieldPairs() macro from standard lib. But I think you and all your aliases know that well already.

Comment: note there is an excellent vector math library that covers 2d and 3d vector math: https://github.com/treeform/vmath Incidentally, they are able to define operations over a bunch of different types of 2d and 3d vectors and they chose to use a template approach to "lift" operations to vectors: https://github.com/treeform/vmath/blob/master/src/vmath.nim#L689

Comment: @pietroppeter thanks I saw "vmath" library, but forgot about it, will check it out.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved using `ForStmtLoop` macros and some magic from `std/typetraits`. The basic idea is to create a two-stage macro, where the first part would simply generate necessary boilerplate calls to `tupleLen` and other typetraits features, and second one will do the actual codegen.

```py
import std/[macros, typetraits, sequtils]

macro tuplePairsAux(
    lens: static[seq[int]],
    body: untyped,
    index: static[string],
    injectsOf: static[seq[string]],
    tuples: varargs[untyped]): untyped =

  let len0 = lens[0]
  if anyIt(lens, it != len0):
    error("'tuplePairs' requires to use tuples of equal lenght", tuples[0])

  if injectsOf.len != tuples.len:
    error("'tuplePairs' requires " & $tuples.len &
      " loop variables to be specified, but got " & $injectsOf.len, tuples[0])

  result = newStmtList()
  for item in 0 ..< len0:
    var declare = newStmtList()
    declare.add nnkConstSection.newTree(
      nnkConstDef.newTree(ident(index), newEmptyNode(), newLit(item)))

    for tup in 0 ..< len(tuples):
      let name = ident(injectsOf[tup])
      let inTup = tuples[tup]
      let itemIdx = newLit(item)
      declare.add quote do:
        let `name` = `inTup`[`itemIdx`]

    result.add nnkBlockStmt.newTree(
      newEmptyNode(), newStmtList(declare, body))

  echo result.repr()

macro tuplePairs*(x: ForLoopStmt): untyped =
  var lens = nnkBracket.newTree()

  for tup in x[^2][1..^1]:
    lens.add newCall(bindSym"tupleLen", tup)

  var call = newCall(
    bindSym"tuplePairsAux",
    nnkPrefix.newTree(ident"@", lens))

  call.add x[^1] # Pass body to aux call
  call.add newLit(x[0].strVal()) # Pass index variable to the list

  var injects = nnkBracket.newTree()
  for inj in x[1 ..^ 3]:
    injects.add newLit(inj.strVal())

  call.add nnkPrefix.newTree(ident"@", injects) # Pass names of the injected variables

  result = newStmtList()

  # Pass all argument tuples
  for tup in x[^2][1 ..^ 1]:
    # If passed tuple is an identifier it can be used directly
    if tup.kind in {nnkIdent, nnkSym}:
      call.add tup

    else:
      # Otherwise generate temporary variable in order to avoid multiple
      # evaluation of the expression
      let gen = genSym(nskLet)
      result.add nnkLetSection.newTree(
        nnkIdentDefs.newTree(gen, newEmptyNode(), tup))

      call.add gen

  result.add call
  result = nnkBlockStmt.newTree(newEmptyNode(), result)
  echo result.repr()


proc `+`(a: (int, int), b: (int, int)): (int, int, int) =
  for idx, t1, t2, t3 in tuplePairs(a, b, (1, 2)):
    result[idx] = t1 + t2 + t3
```

When macro is first expanded, it would generate initial code that passes names of the variables, for statement body and other required parameters

```py
block:
  let :tmp_5050086 = (1, 2)
  tuplePairsAux(@[tupleLen(a), tupleLen(b), tupleLen((1, 2))],
    result[idx] = t1 + t2 + t3, "idx", @["t1", "t2", "t3"], a, b, :tmp_5050086)
```

Then `tuplePairsAux` will have all the necessary information about tuple lengths, and other things, and can generate this code:

```py
block:
  const
    idx = 0
  let t1 = a[0]
  let t2 = b[0]
  let t3 = :tmp_5050086[0]
  result[idx] = t1 + t2 + t3
block:
  const
    idx = 1
  let t1 = a[1]
  let t2 = b[1]
  let t3 = :tmp_5050086[1]
  result[idx] = t1 + t2 + t3
```

`const idx` can be used in order to assign to result, so your code (edited slightly to show handling of the *expressions* (and not simply identifiers)) might look like

```py
proc `+`(a: (int, int), b: (int, int)): (int, int, int) =
  for idx, t1, t2, t3 in tuplePairs(a, b, (1, 2)):
    result[idx] = t1 + t2 + t3
```

Note: this solution can be optimized further by using `byaddr` annotations in the generated code, or by injecting `let ptr_t1 = addr a[0]; template t1(): untyped = ptr_t1[]`. In this case using `t1` in the body of the loop would not cause any additional copies **and** allow for iteration over a mutable collection of tuples (analogous to the `fieldPairs` working for both mutable and immutable entries).

Note: Another possible solution would be to rewrite loop body, replacing all occurrences of `t1` with `a[0]` instead of injecting new variables.

Answer (score 1):

a reply to **how do I add math operations for tuples of ints and floats without being too verbose?** inspired by how [treeform/vmath](https://github.com/treeform/vmath) [does it](https://github.com/treeform/vmath/blob/master/src/vmath.nim#L689) ([playground](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=3B7u)):

```
# these types are not really necessary you could just use tuples below
type
  GVec2*[T] = tuple[x, y: T]
  GVec3*[T] = tuple[x, y, z: T]

template genOp(op: untyped) =
  proc op*[T](a: GVec2[T], b: GVec2[T]): GVec2[T] =
    result.x = op(a.x, b.x)
    result.y = op(a.y, b.y)

  proc op*[T](a: GVec3[T], b: GVec3[T]): GVec3[T] =
    result.x = op(a.x, b.x)
    result.y = op(a.y, b.y)
    result.z = op(a.z, b.z)

  proc op*[T](a: GVec2[T], b: T): GVec2[T] =
    result.x = op(a.x, b)
    result.y = op(a.y, b)

  proc op*[T](a: GVec3[T], b: T): GVec3[T] =
    result.x = op(a.x, b)
    result.y = op(a.y, b)
    result.z = op(a.z, b)

  proc op*[T](a: T, b: GVec2[T]): GVec2[T] =
    result.x = op(a, b.x)
    result.y = op(a, b.y)

  proc op*[T](a: T, b: GVec3[T]): GVec3[T] =
    result.x = op(a, b.x)
    result.y = op(a, b.y)
    result.z = op(a, b.z)

genOp(`+`)
genOp(`-`)
genOp(`*`)

echo (2*(1, 2) - (3, 7) + 2)*(-1, 1) + 1
echo (1.0, 2.0) * (2.0, 4.0) - 4.0*(-1.0, 0.5) - 6

# echo (true, false) + (true, true)  # if there is no operation defined on the base type it will fail
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, here's a concept that matches an N-tuple of a single type:

```
type UniformTuple[T] = concept c
  c is tuple
  for i in c.fields:
    i is T
```

that means `(x: int, y: int)` and `(int, int, int)` are `UniformTuple[int]`; similarly `(float,float,...)` is a `UniformTuple[float]`, but mixed tuples are not accepted.

---

Here's a sort of `applyIt` that takes two tuples and an expression, and returns a third.  No attempt to be general, to sanity check, or pick a good name--just going for clarity/brevity.

```
import macros

macro applyThem(x,y: tuple; op: untyped): untyped =
  result = nnkTupleConstr.newNimNode
  for i in 0 ..< x.getTypeImpl.len:
    result.add quote do:
      block:
        var
          a{.inject.} = `x`[`i`]
          b{.inject.} = `y`[`i`]
        `op`

assert applyThem( (x: 3, y: 4), (u: 4,v: 5), a+b ) == (7,9) 
assert applyThem( (1, 2.0), (3, 4.5), a*b) == (3, 9.0)
```

---

Putting the two together:

```
proc `+`[T: UniformTuple[int] or UniformTuple[float]](x,y: T): T = applyThem(x,y,a + b)

assert (x:3,y:4) + (x:4,y:5) == (7,9)

assert (4.5,9.3,9.7) + (3.2,2.1,1.0) == (7.7, 11.4, 10.7)

assert not compiles((3,4.0) + (3,4.0)) #not uniform

assert not compiles((x:3,y:4) + (4,5)) #not the same type
```